# How do I add a Rich Text Field to a Custom Sitefinity Widget?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, widget, sitefinity, richtext

How do I go about adding a RichText field to a custom Sitefinity Widget? I am using Sitefinity version 12.2 and mvc. If there are any examples that I am not finding, please link me to them! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've updated the previous Gist to include a content block editor in the mvc widget designer:

https://gist.github.com/VesselinVassilev/31b159a1985f272e85b4ff167e59c8d8

Check the new RichText property.

Comment: Thank you! Where are all of these sf-fields documented? I am currently trying to add a dropdown.

Comment: This would be a good start: https://www.progress.com/documentation/sitefinity-cms/client-components-mvc